# Going to a new page, by pressing a button from a fragment on Andriod studio

Tags: android, button, fragment

This is a really easy question, but how do you move to a new page from pressing a button on a fragment?

The button doesnt seem to be doing anything once pressed, without any errors.

Here is the Java code -

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.help_button_ID);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), help.class);



        }
    });
```

}

```
private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



  homeViewModel =
           ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
   View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
   final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
   homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
       @Override
     public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
           textView.setText(s);
        }
    });

    return root;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an Intent but you're not starting the activity.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Comment: cheers for the reply. After following that guide the button still doesnt go to required page, heres the code i added... 

               startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), help.class));
               getActivity().finish();

Comment: 1 - Log something on the listener, make sure it fires.
2 - The 2nd parameters of Intent constructor is a class, Capitalize Help.class